# Converting C# to apk using xamarin

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2010, xamarin, apk

So I have an application which is written in C# and I want to convert it to an apk so I could use it on my phone too. Is this possible or i have to re-write the whole application?

Answer (score 1):

You can't just take an arbitrary piece of C# code and run it on Android.  The UI needs to be written using the Xamarin C# bindings for Android's UI layer.  Non platform-dependent code (domain, data, services, etc) may be able to be ported directly.

Xamarin's [Scan tool](http://scan.xamarin.com) can help you determine how portable your code is.